# event when Outlook mail item is actually closed

Tags: .net, events, outlook, interop

I have a .NET application which uses the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` interop assembly.

The application opens a new Outlook `MailItem` and then would like to record a log entry *if the email was sent* (via the user clicking Send), or know if *it was closed without sending* (either saved as a draft or discarded).

Capturing when the item is sent can be done easily enough by subscribing to the [`ItemEvents_10_Event.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event.

However, for capturing when the item is closed, I could only find the [`ItemEvents_10_Event.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.close%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event. But, this event fires *when the item is clos**ing***, not *when the item is clos**ed***. Worse yet, the user still has a chance to cancel the action *after* I receive the event. What happens is:

1. My application opens the new `MailItem`.
2. The user clicks the close button.
3. **`ItemEvents_10_Event.Close` is fired**.
4. Control returns to Outlook which *then* presents Outlook's "Do you want to save changes (Yes/No/Cancel)" dialog.
5. The user presses Cancel. *(I get no notification)*
6. The user then can do whatever they want including sending the email or closing it again.

Is there a way to either:

- Subscribe to an event which notifies me when the item is clos**ed**, not closing? *(best)*
- Or, know when the user presses Cancel in the above scenario? *(a hack but it will do)*

A bonus would be if I could differentiate if the email was *closed and discarded* vs *saved as a draft*.

Comment: How about check the drafts folder and the sent items folder? It would eliminate the need for catching events. I think each unique item has some UUID that you can track.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's a good option, I suppose I would have to check *all* drafts folders and sent items folders if the user has more than one. How could I know when the user has decided to close and discard the message though?

Comment: If the message is discarded, it won't be in the drafts or sent items; you won't even find it in the deleted items folder.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid So I could poll if the inspector is still open, and if not then it would have been discarded. Sounds like a heck of a hack but thank you. If nobody has a better option I will go with this.

Answer (score 6):

Use the inspector close event:

```
inspector = mailItem.GetInspector;
((InspectorEvents_10_Event) inspector).Close += CloseEventHandler;

void CloseEventHandler(){
    //execute only when email window is closed or closing
    // without problem with confirmation dialog (yes/no/cancel)
}
```

To resolve *closing* or *closed* problem, you can check mailItem send event. If it has fired, then "closing", otherwise, user closed window without sending email.